# Using a variable to select the databse connection in Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, database-connection

I am new to Laravel and am working on an application that uses data provided from an external source which comes in more than forty separate databases. I have to select which database will be queried at run time based on a number of form fields.

I can get this to work by creating multiple connections in database.php and then using a switch statement in the controller to select the database, so it looks something like:

```
case "1":

$data_rows = DB::connection('mysqlxa01')->table('clientdata')
   ->select('column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4')
   ->where('column5', 'LIKE', "__MN57XX")
   ->get();
   break;

case "2":

$data_rows = DB::connection('mysqlxa02')->table('clientdata')
   ->select('column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4')
   ->where('column5', 'LIKE', "__MN57XX")
   ->get();
   break;
```

and so on.  I have simplified the names of the columns and the query as that's not really relevant to the question.

The issue is that I have a switch statement with more than forty 'case' statements that are identical except for the database connection name.

It is possible to generate the name of the required database from the submitted form data as the names follow a predictable sequence and it would seem to be much cleaner if I could pass the name of the database to the DB:connection using a variable, so it would look something like:

```
 $data_rows = DB::connection($selected_database)->table('clientdata')
   ->select('column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4')
   ->where('column5', 'LIKE', "__MN57XX")
   ->get();
   break;
```

This would remove the need for the 'switch' statement altogether.

When I try to do this what happens is that the query returns no errors but the $data_rows object is empty. I'm not sure if what I want to do is possible and maybe I have to stay with the long switch statement which does work as required, but it feels like it should be possible to do something like what I want.  I just can't figure it out and any guidance would be very helpful.

Comment: It should definitely be possible!

Comment: Yes, it feels like it should, but I am not at all an expert with Laravel and I have been googling this for quite some time without coming up with anything.  In other respects Laravel seems to allow you to do things very easily and cleanly but I just can't figure this out.

Comment: @George can you provide more data. Why is it empty? Where is `$selected_database` coming from? Your code should work.

Comment: The $selected_database is just the variable I was using for the name of the database that I want to use.  It could be anything.  If I use the actual name of the database in the query instead of the variable, the data loads and is displayed in the associated view.  I can use the web console to view the contents of the $data_rows object and it contains the appropriate data.  If I use the variable instead of the actual database name, no data is displayed and the web console shows the $data_rows object to be empty.  It is as if the query is just not being run.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I have an apology to make.  I decided to set up another installation of Laravel in a VM to play with and try and figure out the problem with a simplified app, and when I recreated the controller in that, everything worked using the variable for the database name.

So I went back to the original instance of Laravel and cut and pasted the code from the VM into the relevant controller, and it now works.

Somewhere there must have been an issue with the cache, or maybe just a random control character or something else that had got into the code.  Anyway, it does now work and apologies for wasting people's time on this.